# What is the Weight Of Terminator T900 Female Model?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, one of the main characters is Cameron, a Terminator robot. Her model is (as per Terminator Wikia) [T900, Class TOK715](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/TOK715).

In Season 2 Episode 08: *"Mr. Ferguson is Ill Today",* Cameron shares a bed with John Connor.

[image]

So my question is what is the actual weight of Cameron? Does she weigh the same as normal girl or not?

Comment: “a Terminator killer robot” — as opposed to all those Terminator bunny-petting robots

Comment: ~20 pounds more than she'll admit

Comment: Welcome to 2016, people — we’re fat-shaming robots now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Well they only weigh about 10-20 percent more than their human counterparts.

In this link [The weight of Terminators in T:SCC confirmed](https://bbs.stardestroyer.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=127803&start=0) Zack Stentz (one of the co-producers) states:

> Terminators in our world weigh only slightly more than similarly sized
>   humans. They can't swim due to buoyancy issues, not weight. Otherwise
>   you could just stand them on scales or put breakaway flooring at the
>   front entrances to resistance bunkers!

To give credit to the source:

> Can I quote you on that? I wouldn't be asking for this if there wasn't
>   this idiot running around on the board that claims to know the
>   intention of the writers.

And finally this as to how much more they weigh:

> *Name withheld*, sorry for not responding. Our operating assumption is that **Terminators are a bit (10-20 percent) more than a person**, but not
>   much more. Feel free to re-post that.
>
> Zack

Comment: What other kind of boyancy issues are there? They leak?

Comment: @joojaa buoyancy is a matter of density. They don't float because they're 10-20 percent heavier than a person of the same size. That is to say they are 10-20 percent denser than a human which is enough to make them more dense than water and so they sink.

Comment: @Shufflepants yes i know but the question claims that the weight has nothing to do with this. but if your 20% heavier than a normal human and as big then the boyancy issue is caused by weight.

Comment: @joojaa No, buoyancy is determined by density, not weight.  Large ships, [like the Nimitz aircraft carrier (for example)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimitz-class_aircraft_carrier), weigh hundreds of thousands of tonnes, but float.  For that matter, [Earth's atmosphere is mindbogglingly heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth), at 5.15×10^18 kg, and also floats on water.  Because buoyancy is determined by density, not weight.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I know but the text cites that the terminators weight slightly more than humans, being human sized. Thus their density is larger ergo this extra weight is the reason for the bouyancy problem. Not weight being the issue in a general boyancy problem, but in this specific case the weight IS the differentiating factor as the size is fixed thus any extra weight means higher density. Ergo weight is the problem. But thats not what i asked, if this extra weight is not the tipping reason, then what else can cause a boyancy problem.

Comment: @joojaa So, when A and B imply C, and C implies D, stating that A implies D is falacious.  (terminators are human sized) (terminators weigh 10%-20% more than humans) implies (terminators are 10% to 20% denser than humans), and (terminators are 10% to 20% denser than humans) implies (terminators sink).  People are simply telling you this doesn't mean (terminators weigh 10%-20% more than humans) implies (terminators sink).  They have been very clear about stating this is what they are saying.  That is all they are saying.  If you think they are saying something else, you have misread them.

Comment: @joojaa: Presumably they do not leak, otherwise the resistance would be armed with pressure washers instead of plasma rifles.

Comment: @TMN yes and they would use swimming contests as entrance exams. Swimming pools with mines on the bottom would work dandy. But yes I get that its fiction and does not have to make sense.

Comment: Water has a density of 1000 kg/m^3. An average human's density is right around that too, but our density is not homogeneous. Humans are rarer in the fatty parts and in the lungs, which allows many of us to float on our backs (more easily with full lungs!). Terminator density is about 1200 kg/m^3. If they lack an expandable air bladder, then they have no ability to float and must rely on motorized motions to swim. Presumably arms make poor rotors. Humans are lucky in that their density nearly matches water, making swimming less of a chore.

Comment: @jooja "in this specific case the weight IS the differentiating factor as the size is fixed...Ergo weight is the problem". You can't isolate weight as the issue without qualifying 'at fixed volume', whereas the concept of density accounts for both weight and volume. You're right of course, and everyone gets what you mean, but the specific wording of your argument is false and a terminator would reject it as illogical and probably terminate you because computers can't deal with ambiguity.

Comment: @Yakk: The problem is in the original quote. The first sentence establishes that we're talking about a terminator and human of the same size. Given A, B implies D. Conversely, D implies C, which implies B. You can't say they sink because of density unless you're implying they weigh more. So the statement naturally implies there's something affecting buoyancy besides density, like air bladders that "artificially" change density.

Comment: @zahbaz - it's not really luck when we are made of 90% water.

Answer (score 10):

It's **likely** she's heavier than a normal girl (of her size).

This is found by reading further at the [**Terminator Wikia**](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron)

> **Weight**: Cameron is much lighter than one might expect, as are other Terminators. Though it is shown that **she is heavy enough to require the combined efforts of both Sarah and John to lift her into a chair**.

She also claims that she cannot swim, which is true for other Terminators.

---

This is not definitive however,

> Josh Friedman said: "Terminators' weight is the same as human counterparts." during a chat with fans.

Comment: 2:39AM – < LucasZenHannon> Oh, I have a question. Coltan is supposed to be extremely heavy, right? It’s been shown in the films (and I think the show as well) that Terminators are hard to lift. Why doesn’t Cameron break beds and chairs w/ her heavy ass?

2:39AM – < ashman01> terminators weigh what we weigh

2:40AM – < talli> @ash Didn’t Josh once say Cam weighs about 30% than a human girl her size?

2:41AM – < jfhenry> terminators weight hte same as human counterparts - (Producer + Producer / Writer - http://www.savethescc.com/transcribing-the-awesome/)