# In terminator movies, why they do not detect terminators by weight?

Tags: the-terminator-series

I am not sure whether this is pointed out in any of the movies or related material (books, comics, etc.), but apparently terminators are much heavier than human of the same physique could be. Their large weight is suggested on several occasions and I also found a calculation claiming it is around 600 pounds for a 6ft tall terminator.

So why they do not use (besides dogs ) a simple weight test to detect terminators??

Comment: Has a Terminator ever been known to fool the guard dogs? If not, then installing weight-sensitive floor panels as an additional security measure could be regarded as a waste of time and scarce resources. It might also be relatively difficult to implement in the first place, given the aforementioned scarcity of resources available to the human resistance in that time period. Plus, it'd slow down the rate at which groups of humans could enter their bases, since everyone would presumably have to be weighed one-by-one. No need for that if you just trust the dogs.

Comment: Some models of terminator don't weigh any more than their human counterparts; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142290/what-is-the-weight-of-terminator-t900-female-model